# How to use eventlet monkey_patch and google.cloud.sql.connector together

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql, flask-socketio

I'm using Flask+socketio+google.cloud.sql and Google Cloud connector is causing an issue with eventlet.

Here is the error details:

> google.cloud.sql.connector.exceptions.ConnectorLoopError: Connector
> event loop is running in current thread!Event loop must be attached to
> a different thread to prevent blocking code!

app.py

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch(socket=True)

def getconn():
    project = current_app.config["PROJECT"]
    region = current_app.config["REGION"]
    instance_name = current_app.config["INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME"]
    conn = connector.connect(
        f"{project}:{region}:{instance_name}",  # Cloud SQL Instance Connection Name
        "pg8000",
        user=current_app.config.get("DB_USER"),
        password=current_app.config.get("DB_PASS"),
        db=current_app.config.get("DB_NAME"),
        ip_type=IPTypes.PRIVATE,  # IPTypes.PRIVATE for private IP
    )
    return conn

def create_app() -> Flask:
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "postgresql+pg8000://"
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS"] = {"creator": getconn}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** Please always provide your application code in your question for being able to reproduce errors.

Eventlet seems to be deprecated, this is from the eventlet docs:

> New usages of eventlet are now heavily discouraged!

So I would aim to avoid eventlet. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/issues/969) on the Cloud SQL Python Connector repo to investigate best practice for using `gevent` and other solutions that use monkey patching on python packages.

The `Connector()` object allows passing in an explicit asyncio event loop through it's [`loop` parameter](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/blob/main/google/cloud/sql/connector/connector.py#L97). Otherwise it will create a new event loop and assign it to a background thread. This seems to be causing the error you are seeing. You may try to pass in your event loop in order for it to be used. If you are passing in your own event loop and looking for an asyncio style approach you probably will want to call `connector.connect_async` over `connector.connect`.

See the [README](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/tree/main#async-driver-usage) for more details

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I updated my question with my code.

Comment: So what would be the another option instead of eventlet?

Comment: `greenlet` is more common now I believe: https://greenlet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: `socketio = SocketIO(async_mode=async_mode, logger=True, engineio_logger=True, message_queue=app.config.get("REDIS_URL", None))`
I'm using socketio and `greenlet` is not an option for async_mode for socketio

Comment: gevent is the framework that runs greenlet processes and is supported as an `async_mode`: https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html